# SSRS report is timed out

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder, msbi

I am trying to resolve an issue with SSRS the report is timed out but when I run the same code in SSMS with same parameters it it running in 14 seconds

Please if anyone can suggest an alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably parameter sniffing...

Comment: You should capture and share the execution plan of the actual query sent from SSRS to see what is going wrong. I would also suggest sticking your code in a Stored Procedure to be run by SSRS this would probably make your troubleshooting easier

Comment: There are issues with SSRS when there are string parameters. SSRS uses NVARCHAR and if your field is VARCHAR it will not use the index. If this is the case and you have single value parameters you can alter your code using cast to convert the NVARCHAR to VARCHAR for example     WHERE fieldvalue = CAST(@fieldvalue AS VARCHAR(10))